# linking to staff page, how to setup entry

Tags: entries, categories, structure

I am fairly new to Craft and I am hoping someone can help point me in the right direction so I am not having to do double the work or have to learn the hard way that there is an easier way.

I am trying to get my head around how I can tie pages together. I am creating a page for videos from speakers but I want the speakers names to be linked back to their staff page.

How do I create an entry that will allow users to select a staff member?

I have already created a staff entry page, that allows all the information to be populated for the staff member. Should that be a categories page instead to allow me to have a the user select the staff member (category) that did the talk for the video? Or is there another way to allow the user to select a field of staff members?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have two sections:

```
Staff
Videos
```

In the videos channel, create a Staff entries field type, select the Staff channel in that field's options.

When you create a new video, you can relate that video to a staff entry.

When displaying a video entry, you could reference that staff that is tied to that video entry like so:

```
{{ entry.staff }}
```

If you wanted to be more specific, you would do something like:

```
{{ entry.staff.title }}
```

and to get a link to the staff entry that is related to the video entry:

```
{{ entry.staff.url }}
```

Here is an article explaining relationships further: https://straightupcraft.com/articles/introduction-to-relations-and-reverse-relations-in-craft-cms-with-examples and documentation on the Entries field type: https://craftcms.com/docs/entries-fields

Comment: Thanks @Brad, as I had then entry for staff named "speaker" this was my end solution that got me to where I wanted to be:    {% for staff in entry.speaker %}
                        <li><a href="{{ staff.url }}" class="note"><span class="icon down-2 left-2" data-icon="t"></span>{{ staff.title }}</a></li>{% endfor %}</code>

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for staff in entry.speaker %}
                    <li><a href="{{ staff.url }}" class="note"><span class="icon down-2 left-2" data-icon="t"></span>{{ staff.title }}</a></li>{% endfor %}
```

Tanks for the help and resources!